# simple comparison in PHP not working

Tags: php, if-statement, comparison

Here's my function:

```
function checkForDuplicates($items, $checkitem)
{
    $rows = explode("\n", $items);  
    foreach($rows as $item)
    {
        if($item === $checkitem)
            return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

I've confirmed that its returns are accurate and work properly.
Here's where the function gets called and I run into an issue:

```
$email = sanitizeInput($_POST['email']);
$email = strtolower($email);
$emails = file_get_contents('emails.txt');

if(checkForDuplicates($emails, $email) == FALSE);
{
    $emailFile = fopen('emails.txt','a') or die ('Sorry. Subscriptions are disabled for the time being.');
    fwrite($emailFile, $email."\n");
    fclose($emailFile);
}
```

No matter what I input, it writes to the file either way. I can't possibly understand why such a simple comparison isn't working.

Comment: Some actual sample values for `$items` and $checkitem` would be helpful. Otherwise there's not enough here to help you

Comment: Could be line-break related. You could try to do `if (trim($item) === $checkitem)` and see if the behaviour improves.

Comment: I should clarify, the function works properly and returns the proper TRUE and FALSE values. So, I've narrowed it down to a problem with the comparison in the implementation of the function...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem comes from the trailing ";" here

```
if(checkForDuplicates($emails, $email) == FALSE);
```

It boils down to an if with an empty statement.

The following block (file appending) is always executed because it is not part of the condition.

Comment: Deleted the semi-colon and it worked perfectly. Thanks!